# Spring Security: redirect user based on request body

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have a scenario that based on the request body content, user should be allowed to access certain resource on SOAP services. I can't achieve this using `antMatcher(**)` because the path is same for all request.

I tried by adding a filter:

```
public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    MyRequestWrapper req = new MyRequestWrapper(r);
    String body = req.getBody();

   if(body.indexOf("searchKeyOnBody")!=0){
        //Need to check if user has specified role or not 
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Set<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(r -> r.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        boolean hasManagerRole = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
            .anyMatch(r -> r.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_MANAGER"));

        if(!hasManagerRole){
           throwUnauthorized(response);
           return;
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, response);
}
```

In spring security config:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.**.addFilterAfter(new MyFilter (), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

The problem here is `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` in filter class is `null`. So, I am not able to retrive the user info and it's role.

Question:
Is there any way to retrieve the user info in the filter?
Anybody have better idea for this?

Comment: You can write your own matcher/extension for the URL to do the validation. You don't need a filter. Write something like `antMatcher("/whatever-you-want-to-match").access("@someBean.someMethodToDoCheck(#request))` something like that. Make sure you add a filter that allows for reading the request multiple times else you will run into issues downstream.

Comment: It's SOAP request, so I have to check the XML body.. Any idea how to check that with antMatcher?

Comment: As stated you don't check **that** with an ant matcher but in the part that checks the `access` and you write a custom bean for that.